# Symfony form validation order with custom constraints

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, symfony-3.3

Symfony form validation order with custom constraints

Hi folks,

I have a rather complex form of a credit application which I split into several (form) steps. The "busines model" entity is the following (shortened):

```
Application
  - amount: int
  - duration: int
  - creditUserAmount: int
  - creditUsers array of CreditUser objects
  ...

CreditUser
  - firstName: string
  - lastName: string
  - questions: Questions object

Questions
  - <question1>: string
  - <question2>: string
  ...
```

So, I have a hierarchy of (embedded) forms.

Validation of each entity is configured by validation.yml. I created a custom constraint to implement conditional validation (to meet requirements). E.g. depending on the Choice Type "creditUserAmount" the Application custom constraint validates only the first or more creditUsers.

To validate only parts of the form (as mentioned above with "steps") I added validation groups to every constraint. This works so far. But I want the custom Application constraint (which is class constraint) to be called only if all other constraints of this entity are passed and marked as valid. How can I achieve this?

**validation.yml**

```
AppBundle\Form\Application:
    constraints:
        - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Application:
            groups: [Default, questions]
    properties:
        amount:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Bitte eine Kreditsumme angeben.
        duration:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Bitte eine Laufzeit angeben.
        creditUsersAmount:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: [questions]
                message: Bitte wählen Sie eine Anzahl Kreditnehmer aus.
            - Choice:
                groups: [questions]
                choices: [1, 2]
                message: Bitte wählen Sie eine gültige Anzahl Kreditnehmer aus.

AppBundle\Form\CreditUser:
    constraints:
        - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\CreditUser:
            groups: [Default, questions]
    properties:
        questions:
            - Valid: ~
        firstName:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Bitte geben Sie einen Vornamen an.
        lastName:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Bitte geben Sie einen Nachnamen an.

AppBundle\Form\Questions:
    constraints:
        - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Questions:
            groups: [Default, questions]
    properties:
        returnDebitNotes:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: [questions]
            - Choice:
                groups: [questions]
                choices: [Y, N]
                message: Bitte wählen Sie eine Antwort aus.
        ...
```

**Controller:**
...

```
$application = new Application();
$form = $this->createForm(ApplicationType::class, $application, [
        'validation_groups' => ['questions'], // Only apply constraints of group "questions"
    ]
);
```

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: Take a look at this https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html

Comment: Thanks @yceruto. I already tried that. But the sequence provider is bound to the entity. So I cannot check if the default constraints are passed/valid and then activate a second group (in which the custom class constraint would reside)